# Can Yoroi (Daedalus...) create a transaction with more than two outputs?

Tags: wallet

With `cardano-wallet` or `cardano-cli` I can combine transactions (= a transaction with more than two outputs).

Is something similar possible with wallets like Yoroi, Daedalus etc.?

**Example**

I want to send 20 ADA to address1 and 30 ADA to address2 from my wallet in *one* transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: Pretty sure no, at least not yet.

In the technical flow section, there is a note explicitly stating that it is not possible.

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/multi-witness-transactions-cli

cardano-cli is where its at :)

Comment: Your example has two inputs (two different wallets) and one output. I mean the other way around...one input (one wallet!) with two outputs (two different wallets).

Comment: My apologies. I misread the question, On first glance, I can't seem to find any technical documentation explicitly stating that multiple Tx outputs is not possible, but as I'm sure you've also tried, I cannot find such an option on either Daedalus or Yoroi. I'm sure this feature will be implemented in the future, as it seems easier to implement 1 -> n than n -> 1